# Required field validation is doing postbacks the page how to prevent postback in MVC2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Code for check box list and Required field validation. Required field validation is postbacks the page how to prevent postback.

My View Code:

```
 <% int cnt = 0; foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColList)))
       {
           cnt++; %>
    <% var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ColList), value); %>

    <input type="checkbox" id="ColList" name="ColList" value="<%=value %>" />
    <fieldset>
        <label for="ColList<%=value %>">
            <%=name %>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <% if ((cnt % 4) == 0)
       { %>
    <br />
    <% }

       } %>
    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ColList)%>
```

Model Code is:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Select at least one Column")]
public ColList[] ColList { get; set; }
```

I am able to get the selected columns list its code is :

```
//Selected Columns
string selectedColumns = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < ((reportCriteria.ColList == null) ? 0 : reportCriteria.ColList.Length); i++)
{
    selectedColumns += "&C=" + reportCriteria.ColList[i].ToString();
}
```